Error con lucia adapter
Estoy configurando Lucia para el manejo de sesiones de mi aplicacion, siguiendo los pasos de su pagina me encuentro que el middleware me da error: column users.id does not exist.
Que justamente en mi tabla users el id esta con el nombre user_id. No se si hice la configuracion correctamente
auth.ts
import { Lucia } from "lucia";
import { NodePostgresAdapter } from "@lucia-auth/adapter-postgresql";
import { pool } from "./models/db.js";

const adapter = new NodePostgresAdapter(pool, {
    user: "users",
    session: "user_session"
});


export const lucia = new Lucia(adapter, {
    sessionCookie: {
        attributes: {
            secure: import.meta.env.PROD
        }
    },
    getUserAttributes: (attributes) => {
        return {
            user_id: attributes.user_id,
            establishment_id: attributes.establishment_id
        };
    }
});

declare module "lucia" {
    interface Register {
        Lucia: typeof lucia;
    }
}

middleware.ts
import { lucia } from "./auth";
import { verifyRequestOrigin } from "lucia";
import { defineMiddleware } from "astro:middleware";

export const onRequest = defineMiddleware(async (context, next) => {
    if (context.request.method !== "GET") {
        const originHeader = context.request.headers.get("Origin");
        const hostHeader = context.request.headers.get("Host");
        if (!originHeader || !hostHeader || !verifyRequestOrigin(originHeader, [hostHeader])) {
            return new Response(null, {
                status: 403
            });
        }
    }

    const sessionId = context.cookies.get(lucia.sessionCookieName)?.value ?? null;
    if (!sessionId) {
        context.locals.user = null;
        context.locals.session = null;
        return next();
    }

    const { session, user } = await lucia.validateSession(sessionId);
    if (session && session.fresh) {
        const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);
        context.cookies.set(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, sessionCookie.attributes);
    }
    if (!session) {
        const sessionCookie = lucia.createBlankSessionCookie();
        context.cookies.set(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, sessionCookie.attributes);
    }
    context.locals.session = session;
    context.locals.user = user;
    return next();
});

Viendo el /node_modules/@lucia-auth/adapter-postgresql/dist/base.js
async getUserFromSessionId(sessionId) {
        const result = await this.controller.get(`SELECT ${this.escapedUserTableName}.* FROM ${this.escapedSessionTableName} INNER JOIN ${this.escapedUserTableName} ON ${this.escapedUserTableName}.id = ${this.escapedSessionTableName}.user_id WHERE ${this.escapedSessionTableName}.id = $1`, [sessionId]);
        if (!result)
            return null;
        return transformIntoDatabaseUser(result);
    }

El error parece ser en esa llamada que hace el ${this.escapedUserTableName}.id y deberia ser ${this.escapedUserTableName}.user_id.
